# Django doesn't match CreateView if the route begins with 'post/'

Tags: python, regex, django, routes, view

I've written a small blog website in django. I'm using generic views and everyting works. EXCEPT CreatePostView which is a generic CreateView:

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Post

    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog_app/post_detail.html'

    form_class = PostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I'm routing it via blog.urls to blog_app.urls

```
# Project urls
url(r'^blog/', include('blog_app.urls'), name='blog'),

# App urls
url(r'^post/new/$', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
```

but when I go to /blog/post/new/ I'll get

```
Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/post/new/
    Raised by:  blog_app.views.PostDetailView
```

However this will work:

```
 url(r'^new/post/$', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
```

Now if I go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/new/post/
```

I see my form.

No matter what I write after the slash if the first part is 'post/' it will 404 me. At least that's what I believe I have observed. 
It works the opposite direction too:

```
url(r'^somesuperlongroute/add/$',
    views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
```

This works, but that's how it is supposed to be.

What's so specific about having 'post' in the first part of the route? I have 5 other routes beginning with 'post/' which work, actually maybe I'll just include this file here:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

app_name = 'blog_app'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$',
        views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^post/new/$',
        views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    url(r'^drafts/$', views.DraftListView.as_view(), name='post_draft_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/remove/$',
        views.PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_remove'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/publish/$',
        views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/comment/$',
        views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/$',
        views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$',
        views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
]
```

Any ideas? I can provide models, views, forms whatever you'd like but I didn't find them relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will use the first matching regex, which in this case is `r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'`. This routes to `PostDetailView` with a slug of `new`. Since you don't have a post with that slug, the view will raise a 404.

To fix this, simply put the `CreatePostView` above the `PostDetailView`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^post/new/$',
        views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I didn't think about it, thank you :)